# how to get random row values from a table and storing it in an array to be called individually

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to declare 3 random rows from a table to be used as a cluster centroid

the tabel name is data_kuesioner and contains columns variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4,variable5

how to select 3 different random row and the values then call its individual value eg :

```
$centroid1cluster1 = (random row 1 variable 1)
$centroid2cluster1 = (random row 1 variable 2)
$centroid3cluster1 = (random row 1 variable 3)
$centroid4cluster1 = (random row 1 variable 4)
$centroid5cluster1 = (random row 1 variable 5)

$centroid1cluster2 = (random row 2 variable 1)
$centroid2cluster2 = (random row 2 variable 2)
$centroid3cluster2 = (random row 2 variable 3)
$centroid4cluster2 = (random row 2 variable 4)
$centroid5cluster2 = (random row 2 variable 5)

 $centroid1cluster3 = (random row 3 variable 1)
$centroid2cluster3 = (random row 3 variable 2)
$centroid3cluster3 = (random row 3 variable 3)
$centroid4cluster3 = (random row 3 variable 4)
$centroid5cluster3 = (random row 3 variable 5)
```

etc.

Comment: what did you try so far to achieve your out put?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To get exactly 3 and Random rows you can use below query

```
$sql = $this->db->query("select variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4,variable5 from data_kuesioner order by RAND() limit 3");
echo'<pre>';print_r($sql->result());die;
```

> with Method chaining

```
$this->db->select("variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4,variable5");
$this->db->from('data_kuesioner');
//$this->db->order_by('variable1','RANDOM');
//or
$this->db->order_by('rand()');
$this->db->limit(3);
$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $j = 1;
    $dynamicVariable = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
       $dynamicVariable['centroid1cluster'.$j]= $row['variable1'];
       $dynamicVariable['centroid2cluster'.$j] = $row['variable2'];
       $dynamicVariable['centroid3cluster'.$j] = $row['variable3'];
       $dynamicVariable['centroid4cluster'.$j] = $row['variable4'];
       $dynamicVariable['centroid5cluster'.$j] = $row['variable5'];
       $j++;
    }
}
echo'<pre>';print_r($dynamicVariable);die;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, however i still dont know how to assign the query to the variables eg : $centroid1cluster1 = (query of row 1 variable 1)?

Comment: do you want me to provide/help in your further code?

Comment: just one more question, for example i want to do 6 - centroid1cluster1 for example i should use 6-$centroid1cluster1? or is that wrong

Comment: you need to do `$dynamicVariable['centroid6cluster'.$j] = $row['variable6'];`

Comment: sorry i meant a number (6) minus centroid1cluster1, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use array_rand('$var',2)

$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");

$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);

echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";

[Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)